# Database design issue: product of multiple types

Tags: database, database-design

I'm stuck at a problem where I'm supposed to make a database for one manufacturing company. Basically the problem is as follows:

The company produces many types of shoes (products) under different product names.

For instance, "shoe design" (ie. how it looks, no matter materials used) code can be "1048" and the simplest product of that specific design would be "1048 P07" where the same material (P07) is used everywhere. However, you can have some very advanced shoes made, that is, many different materials stitched together, and so the final code could be "1048 P07 T44L T22 L18".

I'm not sure how exactly should I setup the tables and relationships.

The problem is that a specific material can be used at different parts of shoe (ie. different areas/work required to place it there) and so it is not a question of simple adding the numbers up.

For instance a shoes "1048 P07 T44" is slightly more expensive than "1048 T44 P07" because material T44 is more expensive and used on bigger area in second shoe type.

Furthermore, every "shoe design", meaning that for instance in design "995" there are only up to 3 different materials used (split into roughly 3 equally big parts), but in "548" there can be up to 8 (split into 2 big equal parts and 6 other smaller parts).

This means that if I made table with "Products", they are all very different to be in same table I think (ie. one has 3 parts that needs to be stitched, another 8 and some can even have 15). How can I easily attribute what actions need to be done on different products and have the products in same table?

I'm happy to provide any further info if it will help you understand my problem.

Comment: If using a rdbms the point of moddeling is to separate your data = more tables as opposed to a single spread sheet. Make tables representing each aspect. That could in your case be a design table, a part table, a material table, which would function as lists. Then a design_part_material table combining these three values between design/part/material ie. design X, part Y is material Z. You then represent your full product code by querying that table joining the three lists.

Comment: My problem is that every design can have many different parts and so I do not know how to make a specific table, containing list of all design, where say, designId 1 has 2 parts and designId 2 has 5 parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MySql version of what I am recommending. Hope that helps:

```
create table design_list (
    did int primary key,
    dname varchar(30) not null
);
create table part_list (
    pid int primary key,
    pname varchar(30) not null,
    price decimal(10,3)
);
create table material_list (
    mid int primary key,
    mname varchar(30) not null
);
create table design_part_material (
    did int references desing_list (did),
    pid int references part_list (pid),
    mid int references material_list (mid),
    constraint primary key (did , pid , mid)
);

insert into design_list values (1,'Panic Sneaks');
insert into design_list values (2,'Rubber Sole');

insert into part_list values (1,'Toe cap',1.2);
insert into part_list values (2,'Heel1',2);
insert into part_list values (3,'Heel2',.6);
insert into part_list values (4,'Heel cap',1.1);

insert into material_list values (1,'Egg Yolk');
insert into material_list values (2,'Asfalt');

insert into design_part_material values (1,1,1);
insert into design_part_material values (1,2,1);
insert into design_part_material values (1,4,2);
insert into design_part_material values (2,1,1);
insert into design_part_material values (2,3,2);
```

And you can query it like:

```
select 
    dl.dname,
    group_concat(concat(pl.pname, '(', ml.mname, ')')
        order by pl.price desc) parts, sum(pl.price) price
from
    design_part_material dpm
        join
    design_list dl USING (did)
        join
    part_list pl USING (pid)
        join
    material_list ml USING (mid)
group by dl.dname
;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. At the moment I use Access (this company is not big enough and the end users are not advanced enough to use SQL) but I can clearly see from your code how the tables interact and so it was of great help.